# How are you supposed to get the DacPac version from a SQL database script in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL won't let you hit other databases when running in context of a script in the deployed database, so running
`SELECT type_version FROM master.dbo.sysdac_instances`
just results in the error:

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.sysdac_instances' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I'm trying to use a manually run deployment script that leverages the version, but it needs to run in the connection to the deployed database, and Azure isn't letting it reach `master`. Is there an alternative way to get the DacPac version?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the database name in the query unless you are in the same database. Your query will execute fine from the master database.

Alternatively, you need to create the cross-database connection and create an external table to query the data in master.

You can refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) for cross-database queries.

Comment: I know I can't make a cross database query, I was asking if there's an alternative way to get the DacPac version from the app database that is actually dacpac'd. Seems to me an application should be aware of it's own version, and MS has apparently made that hard to do.